# I need some help in \chapter

Tags: titles

I want do the title chapter as **Chapter 1. I need your help**. Not as:

**Chapter 1**

**I need your help**

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{0pt}[0pt] 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\bfseries\Large} {\filcenter\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter} {0ex} { \filcenter\Huge } 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{I need your help} 
\end{document}.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I use \documentclass{book} \usepackage{titlesec} \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{0pt}[0pt]
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\filcenter\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{0ex}
{
\filcenter\Huge
} \begin{document} \chapter{I need your help} \end{document}. I tried to change something but it's not as I want.

Comment: please add the code to your post above, not as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this. Play around with the `0.42em` until the hanging looks good for you.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{0.42em}{}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge} % imitates the original from `book`

\begin{document}
    \chapter{I need your help}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without using external packages, you could tinker with the definition of the `\@makechapterhead` macro given in `book.cls`. (Note that the following approach works for the `book` documentclass and is not guaranteed to work under other classes.)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter.\space \Huge #1
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
      \fi
    \fi
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{I need your help}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want "Chapter X" and the title to be of the same size, you just have to write:

```
\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter.\space #1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done. But my school wants me to make the title chapter in the center of its line and the page number on the top center of page. Please help me.

Comment: @man: It's probably best if you update your question instead of using comments. In particular, try to be a bit more specific about what you want; for example the `book` class has headers on the top of pages: what about those if you want the page number to be centered?